# Word for something required by most but not all

Tags: single-word-requests

Need a word that can describe a situation where the majority of the population is required to do something. Because not the entire population is required, required itself, mandatory, and similar such words are not entirely appropriate. This word needs to convey the same sense of authoritativeness that required does.

Ex. will need a heading to describe a section of trainings that must be completed by most of our employees.

Comment: Does it make sense to come up with a term for the category of activity or the category of the population for whom it is required? For example, Data Privacy Training, or IT Required Training?

Comment: *The majority* also means *most*. If you are ruling out both *most* and *majority* you should explain what's wrong with them.

Comment: @EliotK I can't come up with a category of activity because the trainings are very different. For example, grouped together are safety trainings, skills trainings, etc. The primary factor grouping them together is that most of our employees are required to complete them.

Comment: @JasonBassford Sorry for not explaining fully. _Majority_ and _most_ work meaning-wise but not structurally the way that I want. In order to use most for example, I would have to use a heading that reads "Required Trainings for Most". I was hoping for a word that combines the ideas of _required_ and _most_. So that the structure of the heading could be "[word here] Trainings".

Comment: @CallistaHoxie, do you NEED to specify that not everyone is required if some are? If the key takeaway is that some people are required to take training, is it worth specifying the "most" part of it and just let people figure it out?

Comment: @EliotK I suppose that would be the simplest option.

Comment: The key question is *who* is required? Is it the reader? Is it some group defined in the text? Or is it some non-specific group to be determined later or by random? If it is the latter, you could say "generally necessary" or "normally mandatory" - this introduces the concept of special or abnormal cases, which are usually understood to only apply to a minority, but without specifying what they are.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to supply a sample sentence.  But here goes:

**[standard](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/standard)**: usual or expected; not involving something special or extra: 
*a standard contract* (Cambridge)

Example:

> If you've already completed the standard safety training, I can go ahead and etc.

**[default](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/default)**: A default situation is what exists or happens unless someone or something changes it. *He appeared unimpressed; but then, unimpressed was his default state.* (Collins)

> If you've already completed the default safety training, I can go ahead and etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question.
"Most" [as a determiner] means nearly all of: most oranges are sweeter than these | [as pronoun] : I spent most of the winter on the coast.

Most employees shall be required to attend sensitivity training.

You can also try:

Practically, which as an adverb means virtually; almost

Practically all employees shall...

Use a thesaurus and search for "most" if you need more options.